# Regex slash capture python

Tags: regex

I am trying to match `root`, `root/more`, but not `roots` or `root/`.

I tried `re.match('/root?(/.*)',line)` but that got `root/` and not `root`.

Comment: Change `/root?(/.*)` to `/root?(/.+)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this anchored regex:

```
^root(/.+)?$
```

This will enforce at least 1 char after `root/` or it will just match root since `(/.+)?` makes later part optional.

**Tests:**

```
>>> print re.match('^root(/.+)?$', 'root')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x1014bdcd8>

>>> print re.match('^root(/.+)?$', 'root/')
None

>>> print re.match('^root(/.+)?$', 'root/more')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x1014bdcd8>

>>> print re.match('^root(/.+)?$', 'roots')
None
```